# How to improve the execution speed of code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, execution

I am new to JS, so I have couple of questions.

1. In JS, how can we calculate memory consume by code/code-block and which block is taking what time. Any articles/blogs will be big help.
2. Below code execute successfully but exceeds execution time. How can i reduce the execution time of the code. Any tips will be helpful.

Problem Statement : given a range L to T. Find such numbers whose all digits are a multiple of K.

Input for code:
The first line contains the number of test cases.
Next lines contain integers. (L T K)

5
5 10 5
20 40 2
300 600 3

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                               // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
    // process.stdout.write("Hi, " + input + ".\n");       // Writing output to STDOUT
    input = input.split('\n');
    // console.log(input);
    let T = parseInt(input[0])+1;
    for(var i=1;i<T;i++){
        let d=input[i].split(' ');
    calc(parseInt( d[0]),parseInt( d[1]),parseInt( d[2]));
    }
}

function calc(T,L,k){
    ar=[];
    for(let i = T;i<=L;i++){
        if((i>0 && i<10)&& (i%k==0) ){
            ar.push(i);
        } else {
           splitNumber(i,k) ? ar.push(i):''; 
        }
    }
    console.log(ar.length);
}

function splitNumber(num,k)
{
    let bool=false;
     num= splitToDigit(num);
    for(let i =0;i<num.length;i++){
        if(num[i]%k == 0 ){
            bool=true;
        } else{ return false; }
    }
    return bool;
}

function splitToDigit(n){
  return [...n + ''].map(Number);
}
```

Comment: For your first question, look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+profilers).

Comment: When you're doing coding challenges like this, the whole point is for you to figure out a clever algorithm that doesn't need to loop over all the possible values. If someone here gives you the answer you don't learn anything.

Comment: Did the question literally read "Find such numbers whose all digits are a multiple of K"? (which is somewhat nonsensical).

Comment: It didn't.  The only place where that phrase googles is here.

Comment: @Barmar I am not expecting answer, i want to get insights so that i can improve the code quality.

Comment: Here's some "insight": try to figure out if there's a math trick that makes it easier.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The OP is from India. Maybe the original site is not in English, and he translated the problem statement (poorly). It would help to understand if there were example answers.